# Deleted files reappear after shutdown

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, badblocks

I currently have a problem with the disk on which is mounted my partition.

From a recovery partition the `df` command tells me that the memory of the main partition is 100% occupied and indeed there are a lot of files. The problem is that when I remove the files and then I reboot the system these files reappear.

Note: After I remove the files (they are simple text files) the `df` command tells me that now there is free space on the disk.

I'm pretty sure that the file system is mounted as `rw` and also there are badblocks. How can I know if the hard drive is damaged at hardware level?

Comment: Could you add to your question some information about those reappearing files, like filename, path, first lines of content if they are text files?

Comment: Is the disk an SSD, HDD, or SSHD? What filesystem type (e.g. ext4, NTFS)? Mounted with `mount` or on boot? If with `mount`, which command? If on boot, what is the contents of `/etc/fstab`? Please include this information in your post.

Answer (score 3):

You can check a disk's physical health in most Linux distributions by installing the smartmontools suite and use the included smartctl utility at the terminal. Other disk errors such as bad sectors or corrupted filesystem require other methods to check.  You may have this disk check built into your BIOS, which will automatically check disk health on boot.  It's usually referred to as "S.M.A.R.T Status check".

Answer (score 0):

The whole "bad blocks" stuff dates from prehistory.

If you think about it, (rotating) hard disks record data very densely, to create flawless media to such densities is very hard (= expensive). So disks do contain places that can't be read/written reliably ("bad blocks"). In the ancient days, you'd format a disk and mapped out bad blocks on it, so the filesystem (or other use) could know to avoid them.

But disks with "bad blocks" were suspect, so manufacturers moved to keep some spare space on the disk, to be used to remap bad blocks there on the fly and show the (ilusion of) a clean disk to the user. Also, modern hard drives are very complex beasts, with more blocks on the perifery (more space) than on the center, for example; the "disk controller" on the drive has memory to cache frequently used blocks, and quite a bit of logic to make the disk appear faster (some <strike>demented soul</strike> hacker is reported to have booted Linux on some hard disks).

Today's systems still handle bad blocks, for not-up-to-snuff media and such. It's cheap, so why not keep it.

Now, one common failure mode of rotating disks is that small particles shake loose (the disks rotate at high speeds), and crash into the platters, causing damage (bad blocks, it they can't be read back reliably anymore). But crashing into the platter probably shakes loose more particles, the damage incresases exponentially. The read/write heads float very near the platter, any particle coming into this gap can cause a head crash (and a completely ruined disk). Long story short (confirmed by quite a bit of experiences): If a modern disk shows bad blocks, the damage is already extensive, the disk has hours left. Turn it off, get a replacement and hope that you can copy everything over before it joins the big RAID in the sky. (But then again, some users had disks with ostensible bad blocks working with no issues for years).